# When was the last time no team won 3 games in a world cup group stage?

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup

In the 2022 Qatar World Cup, not a single team managed to win their 3 games in the group stage and earn 9 points. Thinking back, I can't recall any world cup which I remember that this happened.

Since the current format of 32 teams in 8 groups of 4, with a round robin between teams of each group was adopted, how many times not a single team won all their 3 group stage games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, the answer is "never"; in fact, all the 32 team World Cups have included at least two 3 game winners:

- In [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup), Uruguary, Croatia and Belgium won 3 games.
- In [2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup), Netherlands, Colombia, Argentina and Belgium won 3 games.
- In [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup), Argentina and Netherlands won 3 games.
- In [2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup), Germany, Portugal, Brazil and Spain won 3 games.
- In [2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup), Spain and Brazil won 3 games.
- In [1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup), France and Argentina won 3 games.

World Cups from 1994 and earlier featured fewer than 32 teams, although perhaps notably none of the 24 teams in the [1994 edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup) won 3 games.